# Loading list view as new items view at all times

Tags: list-view

I have a list which I've added to a page in my SP2010 site. How can I make the list load with the new item view at all times?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but you mean, but if you created a new view and want it to be the standard view (public views only), them just select that just below where you named the new view.

With an existing view you can set it as default under list settings > views

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you have added the list to a page as a web part, modifying the default view from within the list itself will not modify your webpart's view.  You will need to edit the web part and change the view from the drop-down list there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm (as are the other answers...) guessing you have a `List` in a `Web` and the `ListViewWebPart` added to the `Page`.

In the `WebPart`-settings:
[image: open WebPart-settings]

you can change the view to display:
[image: change view]

My images are from a Document library called "Documents" - but it's exactly the same on all lists/libraries.